# Get android bit version (32 bit or 64 bit) at runtime

Tags: android, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

How can I check the programmatically version of the android bit (32 bit or 64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

[java.lang.System](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System) class provides [getProperties](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) as static method  which determines the current system properties. By getting key of **os.arch** from Properties, you can check. I think this is what you are looking for.